# how to solve this inequalities

Tags: asymptotics, estimation

I have to find A and C $ \in {R_{>0}}$ so that :

$$ A \space\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}\leq  \sqrt{x^{2}+2xy+3y^{2}} \leq  C\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}$$

I was  only able to find  C but  i am not sure if it  is correct

$\textbf{My try }$
$$ {x^{2}+2xy+3y^{2}} \leq 3x^{2}+6xy+3y^{2}= 3(x+y)^2 \leq 6(x^2+y^2)$$

$$\Rightarrow \sqrt{x^{2}+2xy+3y^{2}} \leq \sqrt{6}\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}$$

Can  you please  check if i am right and give  some hints to find A

Comment: Are $x$ and $y$ positive?

Comment: Do you need to find some suitable values for $A$ and $C$? Otherwise, you can use that the function $\sqrt{x^2 + 2xy + 3y^2}$ is continuous on the unit sphere, which is compact...

Comment: i dont   what is a  compact sphere is ; can plz explain more

Answer (score 0):

Choose spherical coordinates, let $x = r \cos \phi$, $y = r \sin \phi$, and $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$, then we are looking for

$$
A \leq  \sqrt{1 + 2\cos \phi \sin \phi+ 2 \sin^{2} \phi} \leq  C
$$

Use the identity $2\cos \phi \sin \phi = \sin (2\phi)$ :

$$
A^2 \leq f(\phi) = {1 + \sin (2\phi) + 2 \sin^{2} \phi} \leq  C^2
$$

The extrema of $f(\phi)$ are at $ 0 = f'(\phi) = 2 \cos (2 \phi) + 4 \cos\phi \sin \phi = 2 \cos (2 \phi) + 2 \sin (2 \phi)$, so

$ \tan (2 \phi) = -1 $ which gives $\phi = -\pi/8$ and  $\phi = 3 \pi/8$. So the two extremes are

$f(\phi = - \pi/8) = 0.5858$ and $f(\phi = 3 \pi/8) = 3.4142$

So $A = 0.7654$ and $B =  1.8478$. Using known values for the trigonometric functions, this can be given as well as:
$A = \sqrt{2 - \sqrt 2}$ and $B =  \sqrt{2 + \sqrt 2}$.

Comment: not a bad answer although must go thru checking by community first for upvote. But I thought it can be done by pure algebraic trick and not by trigonometry.

Answer (score 0):

So, I assumed both $x,y\in R$ are real valued.

For the left hand side of inequality we can write:
$A^2 x^2+A^2 y^2\leq x^2+2xy + 3y^2$, or $(1-A^2)x^2+2xy+(3-A^2)y^2\geq 0$. Now, we can think of this as a quadratic function $f(x)$ and find its roots as follows:

$x = \dfrac{-2y \pm \sqrt{4y^2-4(1-A^2)(3-A^2)y^2}}{2(1-A^2)}$

We want $f(x)$, given any $y$ to be positive, for example make it a convex function of $x$, with no real roots (or only one). In order to be convex $f''(x)>=0$, or $A^2<1$, and since $A>0$, so $0<A<1$.
For having no real roots, we need to have $4y^2-4(1-A^2)(3-A^2)y^2\leq 0$, or $(1-A^2)(3-A^2)\geq 1$ for $y\neq 0$. Then, we may conclude that $A\leq 2-\sqrt{2}$ or $A\geq 2+\sqrt{2}$. But, since $0<A<1$, so we can choose $A=2-\sqrt{2}$ as a valid candidate.